# Solving $x^2 + 2x - 35 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to factor quadratic $ax^2+bx+c$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39917/how-to-factor-quadratic-ax2bxc)

If $x^2 + 2x - 35 = 0$,
then $x = $?

Comment: Please don't shout (all caps). Concerning your question: Why do you want to know/what have you tried?

Comment: Ways to solve (or approximately solve) a quadratic include graphing it, using the quadratic formula, using the intermediate value theorem, using Newton's method, factoring the quadratic, and many more. Which techniques are you most comfortable with?

Answer (score 6):

Well you can do this: Observe that $7 \times 5 =35$ and the difference between $7$ and $5$ is $2$, so you can write your equation as $$x^{2}+7x - 5x -35=0$$ which then can be written as $(x+7)\cdot (x-5)$.

Answer (score 5):

This is a quadratic equation. Try completing the square.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:

Since one side of the equation is already zero, you use that 
$$AB = 0 \Longrightarrow A = 0 \text{ or } B = 0.$$  This reduces your problem to factoring the left hand side of the equation.

In general, when factoring monic quadratic polynomials, i.e., expressions of the form $x^2 + bx + c$, one wants to find two numbers that add to $b$ and multiply to $c$.  In your case the numbers that add to $2$ and multiply to $-35$ are the numbers $7$ and $-2$.  So,

$$x^2 + 2x - 35 = (x+7)(x-5).$$

Now, $(x+7)(x-5) = 0 \Longrightarrow (x + 7) = 0$ or $(x - 5) = 0$.  This gives $x = -7$ or $x = 5$.